# powershell - get-acl but filter for security groups

Tags: powershell, permissions, acl

We have multiple AD-Groups which we are not sure if they still have some permissions on our fileshare server. Now I want to find the folders and I want to filter the security groups on folter but it doesn't work. I'm a newbie with powershell

I tried with
`get-acl | where-object access -like users`

but nothing, not even error

`GET-ACL | Where-Object {$_.Access -match "users"}`

also didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Need more information. What is the value of "users"? One value or an array? Make sure you know the difference between using `-match`, `-contains`, `-in` and `-like`.  Do `(Get-Acl).Access` and make sure you are matching values properly.

Comment: Type just get-acl and see what is being returned.  I'm getting only three parameters : Path, Owner, Access.  The values will change if you start PS as an admin and use -Audit option.

Comment: @Scepticalist
This was just a test, so it should show me all groups or users which are in the parameter "Access". With the command "get-acl | Format-Table -Warp" I can see the "Builtin\Users"-Group which has access to the specific folder. I just wanted to test if thats works when I put in "-match" but sadly it doesn't.  Also not with -contains

Comment: @jdweng Yes, I get the same. But I want to filter out for a specific users which should be in the parameter "Access"

Comment: You should look for property `.Access.IdentityReference` like `(Get-Acl -Path 'X:\Folder').Access | Where-Object {$_.IdentityReference -match 'users'}`